# Recovering a specific line in multiple .txt in a directory using Perl

Tags: perl

I have the results of a program which gives me the results from some search giving me 2000+ file txt archives. I just need a specific line in each file, this is what I have been trying with Perl:

```
opendir(DIR, $dirname) or die "Could not open $dirname\n";

while ($filename = readdir(DIR)) {
 print "$filename\n";
 open ($filename, '<', $filename)or die("Could not open  file.");
  my $line;
  while( <$filename> ) {
    if( $. == $27 ) { 
    print "$line\n";
    last;
    }
 }
}
closedir(DIR);
```

But there is a problem with the $filename in line 5 and I don't know an alternative to it so I don't have to manually name each file.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues with that code:

- Using an old-school bareword identifier for the directory handle instead of a autovivified variable like you are for the file handle.
- Using the same variable for the filename and file handle is pretty strange.
- You don't check to see if the file is a directory or something else other than a plain file before trying to open it.
- `$27`?
- You never assign anything to that `$line` variable before printing it.
- Unless `$directory` is your program's current working directory, you're running into an issue mentioned in the [`readdir` documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/functions/readdir.html)

  > If you're planning to filetest the return values out of a readdir, you'd better prepend the directory in question. Otherwise, because we didn't chdir there, it would have been testing the wrong file.

  (Substitute open for filetest)
- **Always** `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

---

Personally, if you just want to print the 27th line of a large number of files, I'd turn to `awk` and `find` (Using its `-exec` test to avoid potential errors about the command line maximum length being hit):

```
find directory/ -maxdepth 1 -type -f -exec awk 'FNR == 27 { print FILENAME; print }' \{\} \+
```

If you're on a Windows system without standard unix tools like those installed, or it's part of a bigger program, a fixed up `perl` way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw/say/;
use File::Spec;

my $directory = shift;
opendir(my $dh, $directory);
while (my $filename = readdir $dh) {
    my $fullname = File::Spec->catfile($directory, $filename); # Construct a full path to the file
    next unless -f $fullname; # Only look at regular files
    open my $fh, "<", $fullname;
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        if ($. == 27) {
            say $fullname;
            print $line;
            last;
        }
    }
    close $fh;
}
closedir $dh;
```

You might also consider using [`glob`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/functions/glob.html) to get the filenames instead of `opendir`/`readdir`/`closedir`.

And if you have [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) available, a simpler version is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw/say/;
use Path::Tiny;

my $directory = shift;
my $dir = path $directory;
for my $file ($dir->children) {
    next unless -f $file;
    my @lines = $file->lines({count => 27});
    if (@lines == 27) {
        say $file;
        print $lines[-1];
    }
}
```